# Flywaydb Migration freezes

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, maven, flyway

I am using postgres 9.4 in a docker container for a project. It has 9 databases. All database sizes are below 100Kb except one database having sql script size of 219Mb. I made a backup of the data using pg_dump. Now when I try to restore that data using flywaydb and maven(flyway-maven-plugin 3.2.1), it hangs on the last command of the one and only large sql script(i.e. 219Mb script). The memory of the server is 4Gb.It doesnt shows any error.

The same restore process works for an one day earlier backup where the large sql script size is 205Mb. There is no schema change in between these two backups.

I am using a custom  configuration file quite similar like this one here:
https://flywaydb.org/documentation/maven/migrate
and using this command to restore the backup.

`maven -X compile`

The log of this command prints the usual sql script restore logs and hangs at the last line of the large sql script. A part of the last few lines of the sql script is:

```
SELECT pg_catalog.lo_open('31673', 131072);
SELECT pg_catalog.lowrite(0,'\x6c656173696e672c2070726f7065727479206d616e6167656d656e742c20636f6e737472756374696f6e2c206c6567616c2c20737061636520706c616e6e696e672c206172636869746563747572616c207365727669636573');
SELECT pg_catalog.lo_close(0);

SELECT pg_catalog.lo_open('31674', 131072);
SELECT pg_catalog.lowrite(0, '\x4c6f616e2074797065733a2066697865642d726174652c20666c6f6174696e6720726174652c206d657a7a2c20636f6e737472756374696f6e2c206272696467652c20666f727761726420636f6d6d69746d656e742c207265706f736974696f6e696e67');
SELECT pg_catalog.lo_close(0);

SELECT pg_catalog.lo_open('31675', 131072);
SELECT pg_catalog.lowrite(0, '\x436f6d6d65726369616c206c6f616e2073616c65732c207265736964656e7469616c206c6f616e2073616c65732c207265736964656e7469616c206d6f7274676167652073657276696365732c2064656274202b206571756974792066696e616e63652c206c6f616e20706f7274666f6c696f2076616c756174696f6e');
SELECT pg_catalog.lo_close(0);

SELECT pg_catalog.lo_open('41834', 131072);
SELECT pg_catalog.lowrite(0, '\x362f323020546f6f6b2061207472697020746f204166726963612c20666f6c6c6f772075702061742074686520656e64206f66204a756c792e');
SELECT pg_catalog.lo_close(0);

SELECT pg_catalog.lo_open('41841', 131072);
SELECT pg_catalog.lowrite(0, '\x362f3237202d2050726573656e746174696f6e206174203820414d');
SELECT pg_catalog.lo_close(0);

SELECT pg_catalog.lo_open('47060', 131072);
SELECT pg_catalog.lowrite(0, '\x4b657920636f6e74616374206973206120667269656e64206f662056697368616c');
SELECT pg_catalog.lo_close(0);

COMMIT;

--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

The restore process just hangs after the last line. What can be the possible reason of this  behavior and how can can I solve it? Or any better way to restore postgres backup in a postgres-9.4 docker container.

Comment: So you are saying everything including the `commit` works, and the script is hanging **then** (also it doesn't do anything after that). Is the connection still active? Is there any SQL statement coming _after_ that which might wait for a lock? Did you check `pg_stat_activity` if there is a connection and if yes, what it is doing?

Comment: the script is the 6th database in the restore process. It hangs on the last line and doesnt do anything. I do not know about pg_stat_activity and I will try to give the info of that asap. @a_horse_with_no_name